# 1000 questions by New Years?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, good-questions, goals

I think it'd be a magnificent effort to reach 1000 questions by the start of 2012.  Even better if we have at least one answer for every one of them.  At current rates we need about 2.5 new questions a day to do this.  I'm sure it'll drop off a bit over the Christmas period, so any questions you have on your mind about future travel, plans, or questions friends ask you - let's get asking and aim for 1000!

Comment: +1 Great objective!!

Comment: Now it is only 2.43 questions per day!

Comment: 2.37 now.  Of course even if it does keep going down, the Christmas period will almost certainly be slow...

Comment: 2.33! We're doing great!

Comment: 2.12 remaining, def on track

Comment: 50 questions to go, that's just 2 a day!

Comment: 1.88 to go now!

Comment: Now it is only 1.75!

Comment: 1.6ish, maybe we should be going for 1100? ;)

Comment: I was just thinking, at this pace we need a bigger goal :-)

Comment: 1.52 ;) Maybe we could agree on 10'000 until 31.12.2012?

Comment: Only 1.43 to go!

Comment: Only 1.23 to go!

Comment: Only 1.05 to go!

Comment: Only 0.79 to go!

Comment: Only 0.39 to go!

Comment: I'm voting we change this to 1100 :) It'll be tough, but there we go.  Will ask it again when we hit 1000.  We only need about 6 a day to get there!