# New goal - 1100 Questions by New Years!

Tags: discussion, good-questions

We [blitzed our previous target](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/1000-questions-by-new-years), and are going along around [6 questions a day](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/1000-questions-by-new-years) at present.

To get to 1100, we need about 6 a day again.  There will be quiet days (Christmas, weekends etc) but I reckon we can still do it! Let's push for the goal!

Comment: Only 6.06 to go!

Comment: Only 6.00 to go!

Comment: Only 5.80 to go!

Comment: Only 5.71 to go!

Comment: Only 5.67 to go!

Comment: Only 5.27 to go!

Comment: Only 4.5 to go!

Comment: Only 4.22 to go!

Comment: Only 3.75 to go!

Comment: Only 2.50 to go!

Comment: Done. What next?

Comment: We should focus on increasing answers next, I reckon.

Comment: 1600 questions today!

Answer (score 5):

We could raise the stakes. 1000 took 6 months. What about the next 1000 in 3 months?

Comment: That would be almost 11 questions per day. This is a really ambitious goal, but why not?

Answer (score 4):

!

Just as well that I have a lot of questions that I want to ask :D

Comment: Be sure to get 'em in before the 'Answer event' next week then ;)

Answer (score 2):

We have now so many questions that the statistics site is broken:

[image]

Comment: yeah was looking at that.  Was 1060 a couple of hours ago if that helps ;)