# New goal - show some love - 3200 answers by Valentine's Day!

Tags: discussion, answers, goals

We reached our goal of [1000 questions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/1000-questions-by-new-years) AND [1100 questions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/new-goal-1100-questions-by-new-years) by New Years.

Now show those questions some love - let's try for a big goal of *3200* answers by February 14th, 2012!

Don't forget to do at least one answer a day - seek out a question with not much response to it, or even better, an unanswered question, and help push the total!

**EDIT** I changed from 3500 after doing some basic maths from the last few days and realising that 3500 was really quite a strech after the lull in early January.

Comment: All you need is LOVE....

Comment: 23.3 a day to go

Comment: 23.29, we're arguably on track!

Comment: 24.37 we have to work a little bit!

Comment: It's increasing :( 25.07 to go!

Comment: don't worry, this is the slow couple of weeks over Christmas and NY.  From next week our traffic should be up again - looks like it's already improving the last day and a bit.

Comment: 28.14 a day to go now.  Try to answer at least 3-5 questions a day.  If there aren't new ones - go find some old ones that aren't accepted yet ;)

Comment: and 29.70 now. It's really increasing! We have to fight :D

Comment: 168 per day now! Hard work!